# Symfony3: The service "security.firewall.map.context.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.csrf.token_manager"

Tags: symfony

Symfony 3.0.7

I trying to disable csrf protection globally:

```
framework:
    csrf_protection: false
```

And then I have exception:

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The service "security.firewall.map.context.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.csrf.token_manager".

But service "security.csrf.token_manager" exists if I trying use it directly in code.

Full error backtrace:

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The service "security.firewall.map.context.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.csrf.token_manager".
>
> /var/www/studio.lc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:58
>   /var/www/studio.lc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:42
>   /var/www/studio.lc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:53
>   /var/www/studio.lc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:51
>   /var/www/studio.lc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:42
>   /var/www/studio.lc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:36
>   /var/www/studio.lc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php:104
>   /var/www/studio.lc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:545
>   /var/www/studio.lc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:477
>   /var/www/studio.lc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:117
>   /var/www/studio.lc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:146
>   /var/www/studio.lc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/WebTestCase.php:33
>   /var/www/studio.lc/src/Studio/Bundle/AdminBundle/Tests/Controller/SecuredAreaControllerWebTestCase.php:21

How can I fix it?

Comment: did you solved it? im having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

This is the following syntax in the config.yml :

```
 csrf_protection: 
     enabled: false
```

And if you just go to your security.yml file and remove the csrf_provider or csrf_token_generator from the form_login directive.